# How to kill off selected links in a network

Tags: netlogo

I'm trying to create a command in Netlogo where I ask links on turtles with the color green to live while  all other links die, so that the links to and from green turtles live past my tick reset.  Anybody know how to ask for a negitive value? Like 'all non-green turtles? I cant figure this out! Help plz.

Comment: essentially what I'm trying to do is find a command that is like 'kill all links attached to non-green turtles' but I cannot find the relevant code language to do this

Answer (score 4):

There is probably a more elegant solution, but this should do what you want:

<del>ask links with [ [color] of both-ends != green ] [ die ]</del>

```
ask links with [ [color] of end1 != green OR [color] of end2 != green ] [ die ]
```

This assumes that both ends of a link need to be connected to green turtles. Otherwise you can look at both ends separately and work with `end1` and `end2` like this:

```
ask links with [ [color] of end1 != green AND [color] of end2 != green ] [ die ]
```

Comment: Your first version doesn't work: `[color] of both-ends` reports a _list_ of colors, for example: `[green green]` or `[red green]`. Since that list will always `!= green`, all links will die.

Comment: You are absolutely right, I hadn't tested that thoroughly. Using the second approach for this case and connecting both conditions with `OR` would then be another way, in addition to your solutions. I'll edit my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

From a turtle perspective:

```
ask turtles with [ color != green ] [ ask my-links [ die ] ]
```

From a link perspective:

```
ask links with [ [ color ] of both-ends != [green green] ] [ die ]
```

Or fancier, perhaps less readable:

```
ask links with [ reduce or [ color != green ] of both-ends ] [ die ]
```

Comment: maybe `all? both-ends [color != green]`